# Question about using the package exceltex

Tags: packages, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing/Using Exceltex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/installing-using-exceltex)

I have installed `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` and downloaded the zip file from [link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exceltex) and unzipped the folder. Then what? I'm trying to compile the example given in the above link and the instructions for installing and using in this reference is very unclear. Would someone please tell me step by step what should I do next? Specifically how to install `exceltex`, and how to compile the LaTeX file. Apparently, I need to compile the file first, then run `exceltex` (from where and how) and then compile my `tex` file again. I really appreciate any help.