# Installing/Using Exceltex

Tags: installing, conversion, exceltex

I need help installing and using [`exceltex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exceltex).

I installed ActivePerl, then according to [link](http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~doerr/exceltex/index.en.html) I installed `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`. Then copied `exceltex` into

```
/usr/local/bin
```

and `exceltex.sty`

into

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/tex/latex/Misc
```

Note: I created the `Misc` folder myself.

Now according to the above link, when I try to run the simple example given in the above link, after creating the LaTeX file, it says

```
now, run `latex`, `exceltex`, and `latex` again.
```

This is the part I don't understand.

Am I supposed to compile my LaTeX file, then run `exceltex` from `/usr/local/bin` and then compile the LaTeX file again? I tried this and it doesnt work. It compiles, but doesnt give me the result I am looking for. I really appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: *Never* add things manually to the main tree. The correct place is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/exceltex/` (create the necessary folders); run `sudo mktexlsr` after copying the `.sty` file there,

Comment: Could you please post the link you are referring to?

Comment: I edited the post; now it has the link.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your help. I followed your suggestion and I got `mktexlsr: Done.` Now, exceltex is installed? I ran my latex file, still doesnt work. Can you please explain how I should use it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nikandish Sorry, I know nothing of Excel (and I don't want to learn, either). My comment was only about where to put `exceltex.sty` in a safe place.

Comment: Which tex distribution and which operating system do you use? As the manpage of `exceltex` says you need `perl` to use it. So your asked `exceltex` is run from command line using perl. How to call depends on your computer system.

Comment: I have no Mac (I'm a windows user) so I don't know, how to do it. It could be you need to add something like `perl exceltex` to call `exceltex`. The manual of Activ Perl should tell it. Then you first compile your `tex` file, then ExcelTeX, then your `tex` file twice. I saw some pictures in TV about Sandy. Bad thing...

Comment: @Nikandish Is the issue solved? If so, could you write up an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright: No, honestly, I gave up!

Comment: What I do not understand: In TeX Live for Windows `exceltex` is already installed. It should also be included in the Mac version.

Answer (score 2):

I got `exceltex` working in Mountain Lion by applying the following steps. Note that `exceltex` is included in the TeX Live distribution, and the installation may work without [downloading the package](http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~doerr/exceltex/index.en.html)

1. Download `exceltex`.
2. Install `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` from CPAN (`sudo -s cpan Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`),
3. Download the `Makefile.PL` from [the Spreadsheet::Excel-source](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/) and placing it in the `exceltex` folder (I still had mine in my `Downloads` directory at this point, shouldn't pose a problem),
4. Run `perl Makefile.PL`

When trying to run `exceltex file.tex`, I had problems with `exceltex` not finding the correct `@INC` path (or something). That is because OS X comes with its own `Perl` distribution, while my updated version is from `MacPorts`. My solution was to jump into the `exceltex` script and change the `Perl` call:

1. `sublime /opt/local/bin/exceltex`    (replace `sublime` with whichever editor you prefer)
2. Change the first line of the script to: `#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w`

Now it should work! =)

Comment: _(Repeated from comments below the question)_ What I do not understand: In TeX Live for Windows `exceltex` is already installed. It should also be included in the Mac version.

Comment: @Speravir Yeah, that's a point. I was not aware of this when I installed it. At first I just put `exceltex.sty` somewhere LaTeX would find it, but got error messages related to `Spreadsheet:ParseExcel` upon compilation. So `exceltex` might just be installed while `Spreadsheet:ParseExcel` is not. Try just installing the latter and see if the `exceltex` package from TeX Live repsonds?